# PHP output float with decimal precision

Tags: php

How can I output a value like `2.30`? Currently the output I am getting is `2.3`. Following is my code where a 24 hr time format will be converted into 12 hr format:

```
if($openHrs['open_hours'] == NULL){

} else {
    $openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);

    $weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
    $res      = array();

    $todayWeekDay = date('D'); // get today's weekday

    $todayWeekNum = array_search($todayWeekDay, $weekdays); // get number for today's weekday

    foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {

        $temp = explode(" ", $temp);

        $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . ' pm' : $temp[1] . ' am';
        $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . ' pm' : $temp[2] . ' am';
        // only add the item where the weekday is equal to today's
        if ($temp[0] == $todayWeekNum) {
             $res[]   = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' - ' . $temp[2];
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is I am getting `2.3` instead `2.30` for hours `14.30` format. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is PHP is treating your time as a floating point number!

You could cast it as a string, or try `sprintf("%0.2f", $output_variable)`

That should format it with two decimal places after the decimal point.

Comment: Or, as Ankur says, use PHP's ```number_format``` which can do the same thing as ```sprintf``` here

Comment: hpw about 'am' and 'pm'? it didnt appear

Comment: Try using the ```sprintf``` just around the number part ($temp[1] and $temp[2] just before you append 'am' or 'pm').

Comment: So... ```$temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? sprintf("%0.2f", $temp[1] - 12) . ' pm' : sprintf("%0.2f", $temp[1]) . ' am';``` and the same again for $temp[2].

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `number_format($your_number, 2, '.', '');` to display your number up to 2 decimal character.

Comment: Was going to type pretty much the same as above. Bang on.

Comment: Sorry @Qoop Actuallay when I was start answering comment was not added.